# TensorFlow LSTM State Switches from Tuple to Tensor

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm moving my comments from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8833 to StackOverflow as SO seems more appropriate.

I'm attempting to implement a sequence to sequence model using `tensorflow.contrib.seq2seq` and `tensorflow.contrib.rnn`'s `BasicLSTMCell`. Within `rnn_cell_impl.py`, the line `c, h = state` causes the following error:

`TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.`

When stepping through the code, I learned that the error is caused the third time `c, h = state` is evaluated. The first two times, state has type `<class 'tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl.LSTMStateTuple'>`, but on the third time, state has type `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>`. Clearly, I want the third time to have type LSTMStateTuple, but I have no idea what might be causing the switch.

The problematic `state` tensor's name is `define_model/define_decoder/decoder/while/Identity_3`. I wrote the methods `define_model()` and `define_decoder()`, and the remaining information suggests that something is happening inside my `decoder`.

In case it's relevant, I'm using Python 3.6 and Tensorflow 1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found at the above [linked Github issue page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8833).

To briefly summarize, the problem was that my encoder used a bidirectional RNN, which produces a 2-tuple of LSTMStateTuples i.e. one c and one h state for each directional RNN. Then, later, the decoder accepts a single cell, which has associated with it a single LSTMStateTuple. To solve this problem, you need to separately concatenate the c states and h states for the two directional RNNS, wrap this as a new LSTMStateTuple and pass that to the decoder's state.

Answer (score 0):

I think the similar answer can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta/blob/master/magenta/models/music_vae/lstm_utils.py).

The code converts cudnn cell state to tensorflow internal state.

See this method

```
def cudnn_lstm_state_to_state_tuples(cudnn_lstm_state):
```